# iOS EAGLContext presentRenderBuffer blocks

Tags: opengl-es, ios8, freeze, eaglcontext

I am observing that on iOS 8 sometimes my application blocks at startup (_semwait_signal) while calling   [_oglContext presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER] and it clears up after a few seconds, especially on older devices like iPhone 4S. Need to know what can cause presentRenderbuffer to hang ? Any ideas. This happens on iOS 8 only.